# How to adjust width of footnotes in Beamer cambridgeUS theme

Tags: beamer

I need to adjust the width of footnotes due to long title. I don't know how to do it, any help in this would be appreciated. My MWE along with the output is given as follows.

```
\documentclass[compress, 12]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usepackage{selinput}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue}
%\usecolortheme{spruce}
\definecolor{kh}{rgb}{.5,.6,.9}
\usecolortheme[named=kh]{structure}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}
%\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1.1}
    %\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.9}
        \definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.94, 0.86, 0.51}
        \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
        \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
        \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=blue}
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=red} 
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=green} 
        \setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=cyan}
        \let\oldcite=\cite                                                              
        \renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\textcolor{green}{\oldcite{#1}}}
        \setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=structure!70!black}
        \definecolor{gold}{HTML}{FF7E00}
        \definecolor{deep sky blue}{HTML}{3BB9FF}
        \definecolor{light sky blue}{HTML}{82CAFA}
            \definecolor{beige}{HTML}{CD9575}

        \makeatletter
        \definecolor{mybackground}{HTML}{82CAFA}
        \definecolor{myforeground}{HTML}{0000A0}

        \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
        \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
        \setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}

        \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=myforeground, bg=white}
        \setbeamercolor{background}{fg=myforeground, bg=mybackground}

        \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black, bg=beige}
        \setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=black, bg=white}
        \setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black, bg= gold}
        \makeatother
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
\title[Efficient Hardware Architectures for Pseudo-Random Number generators]{Efficient Hardware Architectures for Pseudo-Random Number Generators \\[1\baselineskip]} 
\author[X.XXX]{\textcolor{blue}{XXXXX} \\[2\baselineskip]
    Supervisor \\
    Dr. XXX\\[\baselineskip]
    \textit{\textcolor{blue}{School of Electronic Engineering, XXX University}}
}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the width of the footline elements by defining your own footline as the following. By default, all three boxes have a width of `wd=.33333\paperwidth`, just play around width the numbers until they fit your needs.

```
\documentclass[compress, 12]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
\makeatother

\title{Efficient Hardware Architectures for Pseudo-Random Number Generators} 
\author{XXX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]